# Can someone explain how it is that you analyse the running time of this code, utilizing the proper notation?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i=i*2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i=i+1)
    {
        if (i<1000)
        cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

I do not understand how it is that you go about expressing the loops in terms of summations in order to find the running time. How do you determine the bounds of the summations?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the number of iterations each loop does.  The outer loop goes from 1 to *n*, doubling *i* each time, so it does log<sub>2</sub>*n* iterations.  The inner loop goes from 0 to *n* adding 1 each time, so it does *n* iterations.

Put those together and you get O(*n* log *n*)